# crontab with django - fail with email

Tags: python, django, celery, cron

I'm using django and trying to set up a crontab that executes daily. I saw elsewhere that you can set an email address with crontab, such that if crontab fails, I would get an email to my email address stating that it had failed.

I see that you can do this for crontab, but I'm not sure about whether you can do it in Django using crontab. This is what the crontab portion of my settings.py looks like:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'daily-mailer': {
        'task': 'tasks.views.mail_automated',
        'schedule': crontab(day='*'),
        'args': (),
    }
{
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What help do you need? Have you follow http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Comment: so I saw here https://coderwall.com/p/nwqhxa/get-email-when-a-cron-job-fails that you can provide an email address at which to get any failure messages if crontab fails to run the function. I'm just not sure where to include the email address. Does it go into the args section?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your comment you're trying to combine *nix crontab and celery crontab here.

Assuming you're still using Celery 3.x:

If you configured your django installation to be able to send emails (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/email/) you can set 
`CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS = True` in your settings (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/configuration.html#error-e-mails).

This will send any errors happening while executing tasks to recipients specified in the `ADMINS` variable.

Unfortunately Celery 4.x removed that functionality (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/whatsnew-4.0.html#features-removed-for-simplicity).